# Animating a fling gesture on a Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an overlay (ImageView) over the map on which i catch multiple events like a scroll, double tap or a fling and than simulate those events on my map below. Scrolling and double tap are working but i don't know how to approach the fling event. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn(), DEFAULT_ZOOM_SPEED, null);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    LatLng target = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    Point screenPoint = mGoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(target);
    Point newPoint = new Point(screenPoint.x + (int) distanceX, screenPoint.y + (int) distanceY);
    LatLng mapNewTarget = mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(newPoint);

    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                mapNewTarget, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in other cases (`onDoubleTap()` or `onScroll()`) in your `onFling()` method you can implement everything you want e.g.:

1) scrolling (you need to convert `velocityX` and `velocityY` to `distanceX` and `distanceY` for that):

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    final float FLING_DURATION = 0.1f;
    float distanceX = - FLING_DURATION * velocityX;
    float distanceY = - FLING_DURATION * velocityY;

    LatLng target = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    Point screenPoint = mGoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(target);
    Point newPoint = new Point(screenPoint.x + (int) distanceX, screenPoint.y + (int) distanceY);
    LatLng mapNewTarget = mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(newPoint);

    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            mapNewTarget, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

    return true;
}
```

(also you can adjust FLING_DURATION)

2) change map tilt:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    float tilt = velocityY > 0 ? 90 : 0;
    LatLng target = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(target)
            .tilt(tilt)
            .zoom(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
            .bearing(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().bearing)
            .build());
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

    return true;
}
```

3) or map type:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    int mapType = mGoogleMap.getMapType();
    if (velocityX > 0) {
        mapType++;
        if (mapType > GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID) {
            mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;
        }
    } else {
        mapType--;
        if (mapType < GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and so on.

NB! And don't forget to return `true` from your `onDown()` method or else none of the other gestures will work.

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't get it to simulate a real fling of a map. I managed to do something similar before but it doesn't look natural, the animation is to slow and kind of starts late.

Comment: @Sicisom What is "real fling"? Is it "1) scrolling (you need to convert velocityX and velocityY to distanceX and distanceY for that):"?

Comment: I meant the animation you get when you fling the Google Map on the application. How can i convert the velocity to distance?

Comment: Please see point 1) of answer: `distance  = time * velocity`.

Comment: I feel like we are going in circles here. Have you tried 1) ? Because it doesn't work. It doesn't look natural like my first replay said.

Comment: @Sicisom "Because it doesn't work." - it works on my side. "Scrolling" stopped when finger was removed from screen, but "fling" continued even finger was removed from screen till map moved by distance calculated on fling velocity. "It doesn't look natural" - you can use your own formula for `distance` and, for example, change it every second. There are many approaches to do map animation.